# Create a code to replicate Workflow for Salesforce

Tags: workflow

What are the steps needed in order to create a code to develop a workflow for the professional edition of Salesforce.

Would using Asp.net coding or Java development would work to make my own Workflow for professional edition?

Or would there be a way to push the Workflow form Developer to Professional Edition

Comment: If I get your question correctly you want to get workflows working for PE edition using code? You will have to talk with your AE to pay for Workflows. There is no code you can write in PE so that is a dead end unless you want to write a managed package and pay the fees. And the language would be Apex.

Comment: Workflow for Professional Edition is available as an add-on from the AppExchange. For example see this app. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4NIeEAN